# Zend Studio 8: How to make .htaccess and .zfproject.xml appear?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

I've just begun using Zend Studio 8 to develop Zend Framework projects, and it seems that by default, Zend Studio doesn't display the /public/.htaccess and .zfproject.xml files.

Both files are created when creating a ZF project -- they just don't display in the PHP Explorer view along with all of the other project files.

Does anyone know if there is a setting in Zend Studio to make these files appear so I can open them from within Zend Studio?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the PHP Explorer window, you have on the top-right edge an triangle (showing downside). Click on it and choose "Filters...". Then uncheck ".* resources" and press "OK". Now you see (unix)hidden files in your Zend Studio PHP Explorer.

--

In version 13.6

Project Explorer -> ▽ -> Customize View... -> Filters (tab)

Comment: You are my saving angel!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the file Associations to the particular extension...

```
  Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations
```

Add file type ex: *.htaccess, *.log and add your proffered editor and restart the zend studio.

Now you should be able to dbl click to open in the file in the chosen browser.

NOTE: If that did not work, add the content file extension to the "text" content type in,

```
  Window > Preferences > General > Content Types
```